# MSBuild Project build failed but solution build succeeded

Tags: msbuild

In MSBuild, errors in a target that is executed after target Build will cause the project to fail but not the solution.

Here is a short sample, just add it to an empty project and build the solution:

```
<Target Name="DetectWebDeployPackage" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Error Text="boom" />
</Target>
```

Found a workaround that may be adequate in some cases - change the dependency to BeforeTargets="AfterBuild" however for targets using WebDeploy Package target it causes a circular dependency.

Can anyone help me please?